# A* python trouble, goal is never found

Tags: python, path, artificial-intelligence, a-star, shortest

First off, sorry about the lengthy code snipped, but I feel that all of the code is relevant to understand the problem.

I have a grid.txt file(see the following link) https://ufile.io/9e6hm 
that stores a 2d grid of cells, filled with either 0, 100 or -1. 0 being free, 100 and -1 being occupied.

My A* must find a path from a given start point to goal.

This works fine when I remove the following neighbor condition that checks if a cell if occupied:

```
if (world[yy][xx]!=0):
                    continue
```

However when trying to compute a path that takes into account for occupied cells my code just doesn't seem to produce a result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I would really like to understand this problem. My code is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import math
import json
from time import time
t = time()

start = [1,1]
size = [600,600]

stuff = open('grid.txt','r')

world = json.loads(stuff.read())


size[0]=len(world[0])
size[1]=len(world)

goal = [600,600]

print("World size: %sx%s" % (size[0],size[1]))


def astar():

    pq = []
    pq.append(([start],0))

    print("Definitely getting here")
    hits = []

    while (pq[0][0][-1] != goal):

        currentpath = pq.pop(0)[0][:]
        hits.append(currentpath[-1])

        for n in neighbours(currentpath[-1]):
            if n in hits:
                continue

            newPath=currentpath[:]
            newPath.append(n)
            heur=len(currentpath) + heuristic(n)
            print("newPath: %s (%s)" % (newPath,heur))
            pq.append((newPath,heur))

        pq=sorted(pq, key=lambda path: path[1])

    print("Done!")

    return pq[0][0]

def neighbours(coords): # [4,5]
    x = coords[0]
    y = coords[1]
    maxx = size[0]
    maxy = size[1]
    n=[]
    for i in range (-1,2):
        for j in range(-1,2):
            if (i==0 and j==0):
                continue
            else:
                xx = x + i
                yy = y + j

                if (world[yy][xx]!=0):
                    continue

                if (xx >= 0 and yy >= 0):
                    if (xx <= maxx):
                        if (yy <= maxy):
                            n.append([xx,yy])
    return n


def heuristic(n):
    dx = abs(n[0] - goal[0])
    dy = abs(n[1] - goal[1])
    return math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) 


print(astar())

print (time() - t)
```

Comment: I had a look at your file. It contains not just 0 and 100 but also -1?

Answer (score 1):

Appears you are checking to see if [xx],[yy] are in bounds *after* attempting to access those elements in the world list of lists. As a result, when xx and yy are out of bounds, you end up with an `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Also, your maxx and maxy checks are off by one. If you try to access `world[maxy][maxx]` you'll always end up with an IndexError.

Make sure things are in bounds before accessing list elements, and you should be okay:

```
xx = x + i
yy = y + j

if ( xx >= 0 and 
     yy >= 0 and 
     xx < maxx and 
     yy < maxy and 
     world[yy][xx] == 0 ):

     n.append([xx,yy])
```